# Quota calculator for live broadcasting and streaming

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, quota

Anybody knows what is the quota for Broadcasting and Streaming insert and bind ? It looks that there isn't anything about that on youtube documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube [Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) is part of the YouTube Data API (in order to use it you need to enable the YouTube Data API).  This means the Live Streaming API uses the same quota from the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

As far as bandwidth or how much you can stream goes, I do not think there are limitations.